# Vue 2 - how to bind Parent and Child components - with FORM contents

Tags: vue.js

The idea is to bind parent and child components similar to the example shown here, using sync, but using an Object containing form fields.

(I currently use a watcher on the child component detecting Prop changes in the parent form data for this, which works fine but the sync solution would be a more elegant I guess)

Single field example:

**Parent**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h3>Parent Component</h3>
    <ChildComponent :inputData.sync="parentData" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from "./components/ChildComponent.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function() {
    return {
      parentData: "my input"
    };
  },
  components: {
    SChildComponent
  }
};
</script>
```

**ChildComponent:**

```
<template>
  <div class="child-component">
    <input
      type="text"
      v-model="inputData"
      @keyup="$emit('update:inputData', inputData);"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "ChildComponent",
  props: {
    inputData: String
  }
};
</script>
```

Summarized: I'm looking for a Form version submitting all fields

Answer (score 0):

not sure whether to solve your problem or not, here are my experience:

1. use `ref` and `$ref`, you can set the `ref` tag on your child component of the parent component, such as this example :

```
<div id="app">
    <!-- ref attribute -->
    <child-component ref="child1"></child-component>
    <child-component ref="child2"></child-component>
    <button @click="show">alert child-component count</button>
</div>


// Child component
Vue.component('child-component', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            count: 20
        };
    },
    methods: {
        getOne: function () {
            this.count++;
        }
    },
    template: '<button @click="getOne">{{ count }}</button>'
});

// Parent Component
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {},
    methods: {
        show: function () {

            // get "count" of child component by $refs 
            console.log(this.$refs.child1.count);
            console.log(this.$refs.child2.count);
        }
    }
});
```

It's not only can get a specific parameter or variable of the child component but also can get the whole child component.
I hope the above solution can help you :)

Comment: thank you for the effort, one child would be enough, want to use a form with multiple form fields in a single child. :-)

Comment: then, maybe you can use `event bus` that uses emit and on to get another component since you will define the whole variable of each form fields with v-model of child component so that you can get the variable what you want.